# Transaction marked as rollback only

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have this exception when I try to update a database value. I have to set the `editing` field to `TRUE` before instruction and to `FALSE` at the end or in case of some exception.
This is the code:

```
@Override
@SetEditingFleet
//  @UnSetEditingFleet
public void modifyFleet(User user, FleetForm fleetForm) throws Exception{
    databaseFleetsAndCarsServices.modifyFleet(user, fleetForm);
}
```

This method call an `@Async` and `@Transactional` method and in some case I have to reset the editing fleet parameter updating with false value (in `setEditingFleet` I set the field as true)
This is the async method:

```
@Override
@Async
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void modifyFleet(User currentUser, FleetForm fleetForm) throws Exception {
    //Keep the progress status on DB
    fleetServices.setEditingProgress(fleetForm.getIdFleet(), "Start editing fleet");
    //SOme code
        //Keep the progress status on DB
        fleetServices.setEditingProgress(oldFleet.getIdFleet(), "");
//          throw new Exception("fleet has been restored Exception");
    }catch(Exception e){
        //Keep the progress status on DB
        fleetServices.setEditingProgress(oldFleet.getIdFleet(), "Sorry an error occured during the procedure, wait until restore is ended!");
        //Restore the file system procedure
        restoreProcedure(oldFleet.getIdFleet(), fleetFile, backupFolderFile);       
        //Keep the progress status on DB
        fleetServices.setEditingProgress(oldFleet.getIdFleet(), "");
        //Even with this exception set the fleet as not in editing
        utils.unSetEditingFleet(oldFleet.getIdFleet());
        throw new EditingException("fleet has been restored!");
    }
}
```

The method set editing progress is a `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` because I have to show this String in real time to the user.
Even `unSetEditingFleet` has to be with `REQUIRES_NEW` because otherwise this database queries are rolled-back in case of error. 
The `utils.unSetEditingFleet(Integer id)` is a different class and has this instructions:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void unSetEditingFleet(Integer idFleet) throws QueryException {
    try {
        fleetServices.setEditingFleet(idFleet, false);   
        for(Car car : carServices.findByFleetIdFleet(idFleet)){
            carServices.setEditingCar(car.getIdCar(), false);   //Unset cars associated with the fleet 
        }    
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new QueryException(e);
    }
}
```

When the code call `setEditingCar` I have the exception:

```
ERROR c.e.MyAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler -
                Threw exception in async method Method Name:: modifyFleet org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:523)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:285)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.model.Utils$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fdeb7e66.unSetEditingFleet(<generated>)
    at com.services.dbservices.DatabaseFleetsAndCarsServicesImpl.modifyFleet(DatabaseFleetsAndCarsServicesImpl.java:628)
    at com.services.dbservices.DatabaseFleetsAndCarsServicesImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a9feae25.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Add `noRollbackFor` attribute in `@Transactional`

Comment: do you mean `@Transactional(noRollbackFor= Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on `unSetEditingFleet`? It doesn't work